# Cross-compile multi-arch containers

Tags: docker, arm, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to build an ARM (arm32v7) container, but using an x86_64 host. While I know there are some pretty cool things like [Resin](https://resin.io/blog/building-arm-containers-on-any-x86-machine-even-dockerhub/) using Qemu shenanigans, and [Multiarch](https://hub.docker.com/r/multiarch/crossbuild/) for doing crossbuilding of generic containers, I have a slight issue: The container I'm trying to build starts off as multiarch, and so Docker always chooses the x86 image in the `FROM` instruction.

I want to build an ARM container from a [Multi-arch Rust image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rust/) on an x86 host. The problem is, I can't find any documentation to explicitly say I want to start with the ARM container and build from that, not the x86 container. Additionally, the tags on the image don't disambiguate, so I can't use those to select the starting container.

I've tried editing the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file to contain:

```
{
    "labels": [ "os=linux", "arch=arm32v7" ],
    "experimental": true
}
```

but that hasn't helped at all. `docker pull` still retrieves the x86 images. The purpose of all this is to boost compile times for containers ultimately running on Raspberry Pi; compile times are super slow as it stands.

Are there any ways to explicitly say that I want to build starting with the ARM image?

Comment: I don't think there a was to do that for the moment. I'm also struggling with it and ended using real devices : https://blog.slucas.fr/blog/docker-multiarch-manifest-hub-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to build simple Docker containers for another architecture ("cross-compile") by using an appropriate base image for that architecture. By simple, I mean images that don't need a `RUN` command in their Dockerfile to be built. This is because Docker doesn't have the ability to actually run commands in a container for another architecture. While this sounds restrictive, it can be quite powerful when combined with [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to cross-compile code.

Let's walk through this step-by-step. First off, let's enable experimental mode for our Docker client to enable `docker manifest` by adding the following option to `~/.docker/config.json`:

```json
{
    "experimental": "enabled"
}
```

We can then use `docker manifest inspect debian:stretch` to show the [fat manifest](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/manifest-v2-2/) that contains a digest for the image in the architecture we want to build for. For example, the arm32v7 image has `"architecture": "arm"` and `"variant": "v7"` specified under the `platform` key. Using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), we can extract the digest for this image programatically:

```bash
docker manifest inspect debian:stretch | jq -r '.manifests[] | select(.platform.architecture == "arm" and .platform.variant == "v7") | .digest'`
```

This digest can then be used in the `FROM` command in a Dockerfile:

```dockerfile
FROM debian@sha256:d01d682bdbacb520a434490018bfd86d76521c740af8d8dbd02397c3415759b1
```

It is then possible to `COPY` cross-compiled binary into the image. This binary could come from a cross-compiler on your machine or from another container in a multi-stage build. To get rid of the hard-coded digest in the Dockerfile's `FROM` line, it's possible to externalise it through a [Docker build argument (`ARG`)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact).